# column "location_time_slot.from_date" must appear in the GROUP BY clause or be used in an aggregate function

Tags: postgresql

Here's the query I'm having a problem with:

```
SELECT
    "fightEventId"
FROM
    location_time_slot
WHERE
    "fightId" IN (
        SELECT
            f.id
        FROM
            fights AS f
        WHERE
            f.status = 'CONFIRMED'
    )
AND "fightEventId" IN (
    SELECT
        fe.id
    FROM fight_events AS fe
    WHERE true AND (
        NOW() at time zone 'utc' >= fe.from AND NOW() at time zone 'utc' <= fe.to
    ) OR true AND NOW() at time zone 'utc' <= fe.to
      OR false AND NOW() at time zone 'utc' > fe.to
)
GROUP BY "fightEventId"
HAVING 
    COUNT("fightId") >= 2
ORDER BY from_date ASC ;
```

Why am I getting this error? I want to order by the `from_date` field value that is present in the `location_time_slot` table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You grouped the rows of `location_time_slot` by `"fightEventId"` to apply a `HAVING` condition. When you do the grouping, the information about the `from_date` is somewhat "lost" (which of the `from_date`s of all the rows in one group should be used for ordering?).

Thus you need to either also group by `from_date` (thus all rows in a group would have the same `from_date` and this can be used for the ordering of the groups) or use `from_date` in the `ORDER BY` clause in an aggregate function (like `MAX(from_date)`; then it is clear which of the `from_date`s of the group is used for sorting the groups).

Ordering the groups of rows by one attribute, that is not necessarily the same through all rows of the group is simply just impossible.

Comment: Thank you. Let me have a look.

Comment: Yeah everything is clear, thank you for the tip.